# Cakephp INNER JOIN (SELECT ... )

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Cakephp version: 3.5.

I have a **claims** table. A project has many claims. A claim has one project, a number (1, 2, 3 and running), and each number may be revised multiple times. The combination of project_id, number and rev_number makes a uniqe claim. Table looks something like this (on the right hand I have marked the rows I want in a query):

```
+----+------------+--------+------------+---------+
| id | project_id | number | rev_number | i want  |
+----+------------+--------+------------+---------+
| 1  | 2          | 1      | 1          |         |
+----+------------+--------+------------+---------+
| 2  | 1          | 1      | 1          | <- this |
+----+------------+--------+------------+---------+
| 3  | 1          | 2      | 1          |         |
+----+------------+--------+------------+---------+
| 4  | 1          | 3      | 1          |         |
+----+------------+--------+------------+---------+
| 5  | 1          | 2      | 2          |         |
+----+------------+--------+------------+---------+
| 6  | 1          | 2      | 3          | <- this |
+----+------------+--------+------------+---------+
| 7  | 1          | 3      | 2          | <- this |
+----+------------+--------+------------+---------+
```

So I want the latest revision (with the highest rev_number) for each claim number where project_id = 1.

The sql I want to produce with ORM is like

```
SELECT Claims.*
FROM claims Claims
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT number, MAX(rev_number) AS latest
        FROM claims
        WHERE project_id = 1
        GROUP BY number) AS GroupedClaims
    ON GroupedClaims.number = Claims.number
    AND GroupedClaims.latest = Claims.rev_number;
```

How can this sql be produced with ORM? How is the `INNER JOIN (SELECT ... )` produced? I can't find a solution with join(), innerJoin(), innerJoinWith() or matching() after looking into that.

Comment: And what problem exactly are you facing?

Comment: Is it a way to produce that sql with ORM? Sorry for being unclear about that.

Comment: Sure, there is a way, but that's still a rather broad question... generally you could for example pass a (sub)query instead of a table name (string) to `innerJoin()`, ie `['Alias' => $queryObject]` (see also **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins**).

Comment: I tried putting a query object as table, but somehow failed and lost faith in that method. But you are totally right. ['Alias' => $queryObject] works. Thanks @ndm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @ndm, by using `join()` or `innerJoin()` with a queryObject ((sub)query), it works.

```
$subq = $this->Claims->find()
            ->select(['number' => 'Claims.number', 'latest' => 'MAX(Claims.rev_number)'])
            ->where(['project_id' => $pid])
            ->group(['number']);
```

AND

```
$query = $this->Claims->find()
            ->contain(['ClaimRows'])
            ->join([
                'GroupedClaims' => [
                    'table' => $subq,
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => ['GroupedClaims.number = Claims.number', 'GroupedClaims.latest = Claims.rev_number']
                ]
            ])
            ->all();
```

OR

```
$query = $this->Claims->find()
            ->contain(['ClaimRows'])
            ->innerJoin(
                ['GroupedClaims' => $subq],
                ['GroupedClaims.number = Claims.number', 'GroupedClaims.latest = Claims.rev_number'])
            ->all();
```